# What is the best browser-based python platform?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cross-browser

I am teaching a small college tutorial on physics and orbital dynamics this summer, and want a good platform for the students to write small programs in Python. I would very much like them to all be on the same platform, so we can easily share and collaborate (I have always struggled with differences in paths, libraries, installations, etc in the past).

Is there a good online platform where each student can create an account, write and SAVE .py files, and get all (or almost all) of the functionality of a basic python/ipython/jupyter install?

Comment: [repl.it](https://repl.it/) could work.

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Requests for us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a tool, are explicitly _off-topic_.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb). All you need to save files/data is a Google account, such that all data can be saved to ones own Google Drive (once its mounted to the current Colab session).